# Service worker in NX/React workspace can"t be register because of "import"

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, service-worker

I have a workspace in react where I am trying to setup service workers.

in `main.tsx` I do :

```
import * as serviceWorkerRegistration from './serviceWorkerRegistration';

serviceWorkerRegistration.register({
  onSuccess: () => pwaStore.setState((state) => ({ ...state, isReady: true })),
  onUpdate: () => pwaStore.setState((state) => ({ ...state, hasUpdate: true })),
});
```

`serviceWorker.js` is the same as the default one from pwa-template, I just changed this line to work with NX.

```
      const swUrl = `${process.env.NX_PUBLIC_URL}/service-worker.js`;
      registerValidSW(swUrl, config);
```

`service-worker.js` is the default one and contains some imports

```
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from 'workbox-strategies';
```

Now, when I deploy and run this project, I am prompted with

> Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('xxx') with script ('xxx/service-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

So, I guess the service-worker is not found when loading from direct url. So I added it on the build

```
        "assets": [
          "apps/core/src/service-worker.js",
          "apps/core/src/manifest.json",
          "apps/core/src/robots.txt",
          "apps/core/src/favicon.ico",
          "apps/core/src/assets"
        ],
```

and now, it does find it, but I get prompted with

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module (at service-worker.js:1:1)

I tried using `type: module`

but then I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "workbox-core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I am unsure on how to fix this now.

Comment: try adding `type: "module"` to package.json

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?  I'm having similar problems so would be great if you could share the fix 

Comment: I fixed but I dont remember how at all and we migrate to another service, so I can't help anymore, sorry